# XDocReport: generated docx document error "Word experienced an error trying to open the file"

Tags: java, freemarker, xdocreport

I am trying to generate a report in .docx format that contains a table in it using XDocReport and freemarker.

I am using a list to print the data inside the table.

[image: I am using a list to print the data inside the table.]

The problem is there is no error in java while generating the document, but the generated document cannot be open. The error said

Word experienced an error trying to open the file.

[image: Word experienced an error trying to open the file.]

I was expecting the output to be like this:

[image: this.]

I am using XDocReport 2.0.2 with Office 2016. Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: docx is a zip file with alot of xml files in it. Rename your file to rating_report.zip and have a look inside it and see if you can find your inserted data there.

Comment: @ddekany well, according to this documentation https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingJavaMainListFieldAdvancedTable the `[/#list]` should be put after the @after-row tag. I've tried to put one `[/#list]` before @after-row tag and got error in java

Comment: @Dio Sorry, I have deleted my incorrect comment while you were replying...

Comment: @ddekany it's okay

Comment: @AndersLindgren how do I know if my data was inserted? what file should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a few days of workaround and help from my friend, this issue was finally solved. so here is a change that I [made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8v2X.png)

I added the `@before-row` tag before `[#list p.cities as c]` and with only a single `@after-row` tag. Now, the generated document can be open

Answer (score 0):

I guess (without knowing XDocReport) that `[#list p.cities ...]` should be prefixed with `@before-row` too. Otherwise when you iterate for the cities, the start-tags of the table row will not be repeated, only the end-tags.

Comment: well, unfortunately, no luck. still got the same issue

Comment: You should check the actual output XML.

Comment: how do I check the output XML? and what should I check?

Comment: A docx is zip file, unzip it. I believe it's `word/document.xml` inside that's being generated by the template. Find the table in it. See if there's any obvious issue. Like unbalanced XML tags.

Comment: Also, did you try to simply the word file, to see if removing what part makes it work?

Answer (score -1):

Right Click on the File. Instead of clicking on "Open" click on "Edit"
That's it, simple.

Comment: Well, likely the "Edit" command in the right-click menu would just use the "Open" command via Word.  As the other answer explains, and many comments, a `.docx` file is a `.zip` file with a specific set of xml files.